# Change Item title OnMenuItemClick programmatically

Tags: android

I've set up a popup menu and setted an onMenuItemClickListener all fine, I want to have a 'Block' item in the menu and when clicked it should change its title (or set visibility to gone) to 'Unblock', I'll be grateful for any help .

Answer (score 0):

In the `onMenuItemClickListener` method you should write following piece of code and you're done.

```
if(item.getVisibility==View.VISIBLE) {
    item.setVisibility(View.GONE)
} else {
    item.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Support that you have a menu file in `res/menu` folder.

**main_menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/item_block"
        android:title="Block"/>
</menu>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item_block:
            // Set title to "Unblock"
            item.setTitle("UnBlock");
            // Or set visibility to GONE
            // item.setVisible(false);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```